# How to read JSON file with Dojo

Tags: dojo

How to read JSOn files with Dojo ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bit of a broad question.

If you mean, how do you make a server request and have it automatically treated as JSON on the way back, you'd do something like this:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url: "your/server/endpoint/here",
    handleAs: "json",
    load: function(obj) {
        /* here, obj will already be a JS object deserialized from the JSON response */
    },
    error: function(err) {
        /* this will execute if the response couldn't be converted to a JS object,
           or if the request was unsuccessful altogether. */
    }
});
```

Note `handleAs: "json"` above, which tells `dojo.xhrGet` (or xhrPost, etc.) to attempt to convert the response to a JS object before firing the `load` callback.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/xhrGet.html

Individually, if you already have yourself a JSON string and just need to convert it to a JS object, Dojo has `dojo.fromJson(str)` for this (and `dojo.toJson(obj)` for the other direction).

Answer (score 25):

In Dojo 1.8+, to load a JSON file (not as XHR), use dojo/text to load the file, then dojo/json to parse it. Like so:

```
require( [ 'dojo/json', 'dojo/text!/path/to/data.json' ], 
    function( JSON, data )
{
    var data = JSON.parse( data );
} );
```

Not the "!" after dojo/text, used to specify the file to load.

Comment: You didn't close the require. You need to add ");" in the end of your code.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks, Laurence.

Comment: How can I add my context path in 'dojo/text!/path/to/data.json' when I give the file name in require? Something like this: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]*$/, '').

Comment: Example to access the "config" folder at the current level: `'dojo/text!./config/config.json`

Answer (score 1):

With dojo 1.8:
Add the Module ID "dojo/request/xhr" to your dependencies and xhr as callback argument, then:

```
xhr("path/to/file.json", {
        handleAs: "json"
    }).then(function(obj){
        // do something with the obj            
    }, function(err){
        // Handle the error condition

    }, function(evt){
        // Handle a progress event from the request if the
        // browser supports XHR2

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of  dojo/request module :

```
 <script>
    require(["dojo/request", function(request){
        request("patho/to/file.json" , {handleAs :"json"}).then(function(result){/*success*/} , function(err){/*Oops!*/})

    }); 
 </script>
```